# iPhone UItextfield entry saving method

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Just ran into UX  problem to save UITextField input value.I've got 6 UItextfield entries which saves individual value in sqlite db.

Right now each field has separate save button.So six ones quite look messy and silly.
I just want to know if there is any method to save entry after editing ends.

To be more concise...

I want to save data in UITextField after user ends editing.Just needs 'Saving Logic' for problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use an object which implements [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol. It defines `–textFieldShouldEndEditing:` and `–textFieldDidEndEditing:` methods which are called just before and once text editing ends.

Your delegate should be declared like:

```
@interface ATextFieldDelegate : NSObject<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
}
@end
```

And implements the methods:

```
@implementation ATextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Test if the textField.text is valid for storage
    // Return YES if it is, NO if not
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Store textField.text into your SQLite database
}
@end
```

And you should set your `UITextField`'s delegate:

```
UITextField *myTextField; // could be an IBOutlet
ATextFieldDelegate *myTextFieldDelegate; // must be initialized somewhere
myTextField.delegate = myTextFieldDelegate;
```

Comment: “I can no other answer make, but, thanks, and thanks.”
 William Shakespeare. Sorry for delay but i was just busy in weeding out other errors in code too.